# SuiteScript 2.0 search.createFilter with formula not working

Tags: suitescript2.0

I am trying to filter customers based on a given Email and Mobile phone. These customers must match on both. The search I have is

```
function getCustomerByCriteria(data)
{
    var search = data.modules.search;
    var filters = data.filters;

    var crit = search.create({
        type: search.Type.CUSTOMER,
        filters:filters
    });

    /*var crit = search.load({
        id: 'customsearch1112'
    });*/
    log.debug({
        title: "Data Criteria",
        details: JSON.stringify(crit)
    });

    var results = crit.run().getRange({
        start : 0,
        end : 1000
    });

    return results;
}

var customerList = customerService.getCustomerByCriteria({
        filters : [
            search.createFilter({
                name : 'email',
                operator : search.Operator.IS,
                values : email,
                isor: false
            }),
            search.createFilter({
                name : 'formulanumeric',
                operator : search.Operator.IS,
                values : [1],
                formula : "CASE WHEN {mobilephone} ='"+mobile+"' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END",
            })
        ],
        modules : {
            search : search
        }
    });
```

It currently filters giving all customers with the given email address but does not filter based on the mobile phone. I do not understand why as the isor on the first filter is false so this should be an AND set of filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `formulanumeric` as search-filter, your search-operator should be `equalto` (search.Operator.EQUALTO) since your return value will be number whereas, you can use `formulatext` with search-filter with `is`(search.Operator.IS).

For further reading check [NetSuite's Search Operator](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3005172.html&whence=).