# SuiteScript 2.0 - Logical operator for multiple filter

Tags: suitescript2.0

I have a Transaction's saved search on my Netsuite account and this saved search has some filter condition on Netsuite UI.

Using SuiteScript 2.0, I am loading this search and taking copy of all the filter defined on Netsuite UI (say defaultfilters) and then applying filter for "trandate"  as filterExpression then pushing defaultfilters in savedsearch filter collection.

but what happening is that, netsuite only considering "trandate" filter, not those that are defined on Netsuite.

I assume that somehow between two filters "OR" logical operator being applied.

same issue discussed in another query:
[SuiteScript 2.0 search.createFilter with formula not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55391005/suitescript-2-0-search-createfilter-with-formula-not-working)

please guide me for this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following to add searchFilters or FilterExpressions

1. Load the search

   `var savedSearch = search.load({ id: SEARCH_ID });`
2. Push custom filters in `savedSearch` object as below:

   ```
   // for searchFilter
   savedSearch.filters.push(search.createSearchFilters(SEARCH_FILTER_OBJECT);

   // for filter expression
   var filterExpressions = savedSearch.filterExpressions;
   filterExpressions.push('and', [FIELDID, SEARCH_OPERATOR, VALUES]);
   savedSearch.filterExpressions = filterExpressions;
   ```

As for using formula in filterExpressions, if you use `formulanumeric` as the fieldName, your operator should be `equalto` and not `is` whereas if you use `formulatext` as fieldName you can use `is` operator as per [NetSuite's Search Operators](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3005172.html&whence=)